# how can I draw scatter plot from and excel file using matplot and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have to draw a scatter plot of city location vs. amount in USD. Display "+" marker in cyan colors with size 25 from an excel file. But it is giving me this error that x and y must be of the same size I cant figure out what is wrong with the data.
the link to the file is this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14t4vrfiifgDgBM2MwCbITztVWi338b5D/view?usp=sharing

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn 
%matplotlib inline 
df = pd.read_excel(r'')
type(df) 
x = df['City Location'] 
x1 = str(x)
y = df['Amount in USD'] 
plt.scatter(x1,y)
```

but this gave me `ValueError: x and y must be the same size`

Comment: Why did you change x into a string type?

Comment: earlier I was getting an error saying  `TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float`

Comment: Please provide some example data as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also, perhaps this is obvious, but what are the sizes of the two arrays? Use `len(x)`

Comment: its 3009 the are both equal

Comment: sorry I am new here

Comment: Does `df['Amount in USD']` have values?, I do not see any values in the link to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the problem has been resolved in the meanwhile.
Hope that this solution helps you in the good direction.

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

A simple dataset. As per my comment, double check if there are values in `df['Amount in USD]`, I had the impression that this column was empty.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'City Location': ['Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Hyderabad'], 'Amount in USD':[10,20,30]})
```

Plotting (remove the x1 = str(x) command):

```
x = df['City Location'] 
y = df['Amount in USD'] 
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

[image]